# How to catch outgoing email in Laravel 5

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I'd like to catch all emails and send them to the particular address defined in the configuration if current environment is not production.

I know that I can set MAIL_DRIVER=log but I'd like it to be independent from environment settings and to be sent to the real testing address, but not to the log file.

Where can I do that?

Thanks!

P.S. All emails are sent through the queue.